# How to store multiple values with multiple keys using preferences in Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I need to create add multiple numbers and each of them have unique name from user input. Then in another `Activity` when user put the name, the app returns the number.

To Store:

```
public void addNewContact(View view){
    EditText txtName = findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    EditText txtNumber = findViewById(R.id.txt_number);

    String name = txtName.getText().toString();
    String number = txtNumber.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("contact", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putString("name", name)
            .putString("number", number).commit();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Contact added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

To retrieve:

```
  public void findContact(View view){
    EditText txtNombre = findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre);

    String name = txtNombre.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("contact", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String nameS = preferences.getString(name,"");
    String number = preferences.getString("number", "");

    Toast.makeText(this,nameS +" : "+ number,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now when I put 2 or more contacts and retrieve it, the number gets overwritten. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: In SharedPreferences, you cannot save multiple values with the same key directly. Each key in SharedPreferences is unique and can only have a single value associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can save a value in SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("name", "John Doe");
editor.commit();
```

In SharedPreferences, you cannot save multiple values with the same key directly. Each key in SharedPreferences is unique and can only have a single value associated with it. However, you can achieve a similar effect by using a Map to store the contacts as below-

```
public void addNewContact(View view) {
    EditText txtName = findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    EditText txtNumber = findViewById(R.id.txt_number);

    String name = txtName.getText().toString();
    String number = txtNumber.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("contact", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    Map<String, String> contacts = new HashMap<>();
    contacts.put(name, number);
    editor.putString("contacts", new Gson().toJson(contacts));
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Contact added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void findContact(View view) {
    EditText txtNombre = findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre);

    String name = txtNombre.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("contact", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String contactsJson = preferences.getString("contacts", "");

    Map<String, String> contacts = new Gson().fromJson(contactsJson, Map.class);
    String number = contacts.get(name);

    Toast.makeText(this, name + " : " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Is there any way I can  store multiples values, each value have their own key, and I can retrieve number by key, only using Preferences?

Comment: I have updated the code for SharedPref for saving Key, value.